# Mount moss 2007 web application content database(NTLM) on 2010 web application with Negotiate (Kerberos) authentication provider

Tags: kerberos

Can I mount a MOSS 2007 web application content database with NTLM authentication provider on 2010 web application with Negotiate (Kerberos) authentication provider?

Will I face any issues?

Answer (score 1):

No, there should be no risk in doing this (if we're just looking at the NTLM/Negotiate issue).

Of course - you will have to make sure that you CDB can be upgraded! But that's another question.